# Can't read excel file from directly from path using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, ignite-ui

I am new toJavaScript.  I am trying to read an excel file using JavaScript.

Using the code below, I am getting the file from object "fileReader" that read the chosen file from browse button , i need to insert the URL file directly , code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
    $(function () {
        $("#input").on("change", function () 
        {
            var excelFile,
                fileReader = new FileReader();
             $("#result").hide();
             fileReader.onload = function (e) {

                 var buffer = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result);
                 var workbook = new $.ig.excel.Workbook("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\TrustAgents.xlsx");
                $.ig.excel.Workbook.load(buffer, function (workbook) 
                {
                    var column, row, newRow, cellValue, columnIndex, i,
                        worksheet = workbook.worksheets(0),
                        columnsNumber = 0,
                        gridColumns = [],
                        data = [],
                        worksheetRowsCount;

                    // Both the columns and rows in the worksheet are lazily created and because of this most of the time worksheet.columns().count() will return 0
                    // So to get the number of columns we read the values in the first row and count. When value is null we stop counting columns:
                    while (worksheet.rows(0).getCellValue(columnsNumber)) {
                        columnsNumber++;
                    }

                    // Iterating through cells in first row and use the cell text as key and header text for the grid columns
                    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnsNumber; columnIndex++) {
                        column = worksheet.rows(0).getCellText(columnIndex);
                        gridColumns.push({ headerText: column, key: column });
                    }

                    // We start iterating from 1, because we already read the first row to build the gridColumns array above
                    // We use each cell value and add it to json array, which will be used as dataSource for the grid
                    for (i = 1, worksheetRowsCount = worksheet.rows().count() ; i < worksheetRowsCount; i++) {
                        newRow = {};
                        row = worksheet.rows(i);

                        for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnsNumber; columnIndex++) {
                            cellValue = row.getCellText(columnIndex);
                            newRow[gridColumns[columnIndex].key] = cellValue;
                        }

                        data.push(newRow);
                    }

                    // we can also skip passing the gridColumns use autoGenerateColumns = true, or modify the gridColumns array
                    createGrid(data, gridColumns);
                }, function (error) {
                    $("#result").text("The excel file is corrupted.");
                    $("#result").show(1000);
                });
            }

            if (this.files.length > 0)
            {
                excelFile = this.files[0];
                if (excelFile.type === "application/vnd.ms-excel" || excelFile.type === "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" || (excelFile.type === "" && (excelFile.name.endsWith("xls") || excelFile.name.endsWith("xlsx")))) 
                {
                    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(excelFile);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $("#result").text("The format of the file you have selected is not supported. Please select a valid Excel file ('.xls, *.xlsx').");
                    $("#result").show(1000);
                }
            }

        })
    })

    function createGrid(data, gridColumns) {
        if ($("#grid1").data("igGrid") !== undefined) {
            $("#grid1").igGrid("destroy");
        }

        $("#grid1").igGrid({
            columns: gridColumns,
            autoGenerateColumns: true,
            dataSource: data,
            width: "100%"
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am assuming you are using ignite-ui library. Also, what is  the error you are getting exactly?  I can't figure that out from your question.

Comment: yes i use ignite-ui library , just need to put url of the excel file directly

Comment: @wesam What do you mean by you want "url file directly"? Is the browse button not letting you choose a file from the file system, or do you want to load a file from external source and not from the file system?

Comment: thanks for help , I found the solution after a lengthy search.

Comment: @KonstantinDinev and i meant  that i don't want browse button , i needed to put the path of my file excel to load data directly with out click the browse button.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to the `FileReader` API, rather than the Ignite UI Excel Engine. Here's what the file reader can do:

> The FileReader object lets web applications asynchronously read the
>   contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer,
>   using File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read.
>
> File objects may be obtained from a FileList object returned as a
>   result of a user selecting files using the  element, from a
>   drag and drop operation's DataTransfer object, or from the
>   mozGetAsFile() API on an HTMLCanvasElement.

Here's the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to the documentation. The FileReader itself cannot access the entire file system on the client machine because of numerous security concerns.